# Dropper seat post with 150 mm of travel

Tags: product-rec, seatpost

Are there dropper seat posts with 150 mm of travel on the market other than Rock Shox Reverb Stealth and Kind Shock (LEV & Supernatural)?

Comment: VTC because its pure product rec.  Also, its an excellent example of WHY product rec questions are off topic.  Only 4 years later, this question and its answers are outdated.   The [chat] is much more appropriate for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any other posts, unless they are boutique and don't sell online. However it looks like Thomson, Fox, and Crank Brothers all have posts with 125mm which seems to be the next step down. From there, a few have 110mm and the rest are at 100mm.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good, cheap and reliable cable actuated dropper post online. It comes with 120mm and 150mm of travel!

The 150mm version is £110.

I personally have the 120mm version and have been running it for a year now with no problems.

Here's the link:
https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/brand-x-ascend-120mm-150mm-dropper-seatpost/rp-prod149024

Hope this helps!

Comment: The original question is about 4½ years old. Since then, many longer dropper posts have become available, and the 150 mm travel is somewhat the default now. It is not uncommon to find longer travel posts these days, up to 175 - 180 mm.